# Mongoose - update an item inside an array but unable to filter correctly

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am currently trying to update a document that has an array. The array is composed of a couple of items. My update filters for the `productConfiguration.id` and then updates. However, I am not getting any update. I have tried multiple different ways and no luck. What is the right approach for this?

DB Entry to update:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Test",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "productConfiguration": [{
        "id": "1j6h591kz6wkznti5ta",
        "name": "tester1",
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2022-02-15T07:42:38.492Z"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2022-02-15T07:42:38.492Z"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1j6h591kzepkzntqins",
        "name": "tester1",
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2022-02-15T07:42:38.492Z"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2022-02-15T07:42:38.492Z"
        }
    }],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Mongoose update

```
app.put('/product', (req, res) => {
    MySchema.findOneAndUpdate({
        "productConfiguration.$.id" : req.body.id
    }, {
        $set: {
            "productConfiguration.$.updatedAt": req.body.updatedAt
        }
    }, {
        runValidators: true
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('success', 'Config update successfully!');
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            console.log('Error during record update : ' + err);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter is not correct as you're using the positional operator there. You can simply use [dot-notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to find the correct `productConfiguration` element:

```
MySchema.findOneAndUpdate({
        "productConfiguration.id" : req.body.id
    }, {
        $set: {
            "productConfiguration.$.updatedAt": req.body.updatedAt
        }
    }
```